# How to access mysql datadir folder of host machine through docker centos container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, centos7, docker-machine

I am using docker on windows 10 pro and I installed the following

- centos
- mysql
- nginx

The container inside docker and mysql databases is also installed on my host machine.

Now I want to access the `datadir` folder of host's mysql database from docker centos
container

Answer (score 0):

Map both containers to the same host-volume and both containers should be able to see the data stored there.

Create your volume:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes

```
docker volume create mysqldata
```

Start your containers mapped to the volume: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume

```
docker run -d --mount source= mysqldata,target=/var/lib/mysql mysql
docker run -d --mount source= mysqldata,target=/var/lib/mysql centos
```

Comment: Hi #Eric i am very new to these stuf, can u please give me example for starting container with volume in windows 10 operating system. thanks

Comment: If you have Docker CE installed, then any command line terminal can be used to issue the commands in the answer